# Query polygons $geowithin $box mongodb doesn't return anything

Tags: mongodb, geometry, gis, geospatial, bounding-box

Guys I am trying to query all the polygons inside by bounding box but it simply returns 0.. It should be returning many polygons!

Alternatively I try to query a much larger bounding box and nothing happens!

My query is:

```
{
 geometry: 
    { $geoWithin: 
        { $box:  
            [ [-73.995762,40.764826], [-73.934034,40.802038] ] 
        } 
    }                       
}
```

Notice that the very same query returns a valid result for geometries of type `Point`

[image: Points]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes the answer:

$box do work with GeoJSON, but not with polygons! You need to generate a geometry with the $box instead.

Also, it always has to has the start point and point, so a 4-point polygon will have **5 coordinate tuples**

**BUT it gets trickier**, it has to follow the **right hand rule** (anticlockwise).

[image: it's anticlockwise]

TESTING GEOJSON WITH $BOX AND POINTS

my query:

```
{ 
  geometry: { 
    $geoWithin: { 
      $box: [ 
        [ -71.934034, 38.764826 ], 
        [ -75.995762, 43.802038 ] 
      ] 
    } 
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Not only this contradicts the documentation (up to current MongoDB v3.4), the answer suggests an unproven (anti-clockwise) work-around, along with broken images that does not help the point.

Comment: https://data.ny.gov/ - datasets = "Building Footprints" and "Selected Facilities and Program Sites"

The rest of the info of you can find on the question. Try reproducing it and maybe we can get to the bottom of the solution in order to pass it forward to people who may need it! I removed the correct answer check until we find it =) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating the screenshots with working images. Your last two screenshots are using [$geometry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geometry/) instead of `$box`. As suggested in above answer, you should use `$geometry` instead of `$box` for GeoJSON format. `$box` does not support GeoJSON, it only returns type `Point` because of it's similarity of formatting to the legacy coordinates. For future reference, see also [guide: minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

> to query all the polygons inside by bounding box but it simply returns 0

The [$box operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#box) for [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) only supports documents based on [grid coordinates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/#geospatial-indexes-store-grid-coordinates) and does not support [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) shapes format.

> the very same query returns a valid result for geometries of type Point

Depending on your documents structure, and how you are querying them, this is probably treated as being grid coordinates i.e. `{geometry: [<long>, <lat>]}`
This may not have worked for your polygons document because [GeoJSON Polygons](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygons-with-a-single-ring) require an extra array wrapper. i.e. `[[ [<long>, <lat>] ]]` invalidating the grid coordinates format.

If your documents are in GeoJSON format, and you would like to select an area, you could utilise [$geometry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geometry/#op._S_geometry) instead.

```
db.places.find(
   {
     'geometry': {
       $geoWithin: {
          $geometry: {
             type : "Polygon" ,
             coordinates: [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ]
          }
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Worth noting that [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) geospatial visualisation currently (v1.6) does not support GeoJSON yet.

Comment: Wan, it does offer support to GeoJSON for points and polygons.. Perhaps you have seen an older documentation? They indeed have an entra wrap for the array, but it still works fine, check out the solution I posted.. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Based on MongoDB manual [$box](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#box) as posted for current stable v3.4 "When used with the $box operator, $geoWithin returns documents based on grid coordinates and does not query for GeoJSON shapes" . Please update your post with your documents sample structure/schema so that others can try to replicate your problem.