# MongoEngine geo_within_box not working with polygon

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongoengine, geo

I would like to query `Drawing.objects(box__geo_within_box=[(-180, -90), (180, 90)])`

`Drawing.box` being a polygon of this type `PolygonField()` initialized in the following way:

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [left, top], [right, top], [right, bottom], [left, bottom], [left, top] ] ] }
```

But it does not work (I get empty results). Maybe geo_within_box only works with points, not polygons?

How can I query all polygons inside a box?

Note: `box__geo_intersects` only returns polygons which intersect the edges, not the ones inside the given polygon.

Comment: Maybe checking the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405589/query-polygons-geowithin-box-mongodb-doesnt-return-anything

Comment: When you say "it does not work", do you get an error or does it return empty results?

Comment: I get empty results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I query ["big" polygons](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/mongodb/v3.6/reference/reference-operator-query-geoWithin.html#big-polygons).

`box__geo_intersects` works fine with polygons smaller than a single hemisphere.